# selenium python: How do I find every email on a webpage?

Tags: python, email, selenium

The website doesn't show the email addresses as text, there are buttons that open up an email box, but the email addresses are shown in the source code.

Each email is in this type of html code:

```
<a onclick="CC('palthoff@mcpaz.com', '', '','','');" href="#"><img src="/cpd/images/icons/email_yellow_sm.gif" border="0"></a>
```

I can get to the element by xpath:

```
email = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="row2FC"]/td[2]/div/a")
```

But when I "print email.text" nothing shows up. I know that it would only print the text if it was shown on the page, but then how could I print the email address shown in "onclick"? onclick="CC('the email address)'

I want to grab every email address from this website, but I can't figure out how to print that text.

Your help is greatly appreciated.  Sorry if this is elementary, I've google searched my issue and couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: Are all emails always inside the `onclick` attribute of `a` tag?

Comment: yes. I just found a way to get the contents by using source_code = email.get_attribute("outerHTML"). But is there any way to get only the email addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the text of the email, you could slice the string returned by the `get_attribute` method in your own answer:

```
emails = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")

for x in range(0,len(emails)):
    code = emails[x].get_attribute("onclick")
    email = code[4:len(code)-17]
    print email
```

Comment: I don't know how you did that, but it is genius! Thank you for your help! But seriously, how did you know to add 4 and -17?

Comment: because ', '', '','',''); is 17 chars long, CC(' is 4 chars long

Comment: @Gus Gabel You can count the number of characters from the beginning of the string, and from the end of the string, and use slicing, for a quick fix.  Slicing in Python allows you to extract a substring from a string.  My pleasure!  Thanks for the kudos, and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Code is below:

```
emails = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")

for x in range(0,len(emails)):
    code = emails[x].get_attribute("outerHTML")
    print code
```

It prints the full outer HTML though.  Is there any way to parse what prints?

```
<a onclick="CC('dbennett@realdevelopment.com', '', '','','');" href="#"><img src
```

To remove everything but the email?